# Select secrets older than 29 days

Tags: kubernetes

I would like to create a cron job which selects the name kubernetes secrets from a given type (e.g kubernetes.io/tls) older than 29 days.

I tried these 2 ways:

1 - Using grep:

```
kubectl get secrets --all-namespaces| grep kubernetes.io/tls
cicd           devkins.infra.mydomain.ninja.tls         kubernetes.io/tls  2 14d
cust-ao-xmas   cust-ao-xmas.infra.mydomain.ninja.tls    kubernetes.io/tls  2 1h
dev            dev.mydomain.com.tls                     kubernetes.io/tls  2 4h
logging        graylog.infra.mydomain.ninja.tls         kubernetes.io/tls  2 10d
```

2 Using jsonpath

```
kubectl get secrets --all-namespaces -o jsonpath='{range .items[?(@.type=="kubernetes.io/tls")]}[{.metadata.namespace},{.metadata.name},{.metadata.creationTimestamp}]{"\n"}{end}'
[cicd,devkins.infra.mydomain.ninja.tls,2017-12-13T22:57:02Z]
[cust-ao-xmas,cust-ao-xmas.infra.mydomain.ninja.tls,2017-12-28T03:13:32Z]
[dev,dev.mydomain.com.tls,2017-12-28T00:59:10Z]
[logging,graylog.infra.mydomain.ninja.tls,2017-12-17T22:23:38Z]
```

Both of them return the answers but make it extremely hard to parse

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: Is the requirement to do this via Kubect only? Also why you can not use the timestamp from your second query?

Answer (score 7):

This is what I use... There is probably better way of doing it, but works for my case (secrets older than 24hrs).

```
kubectl get secrets -o json | jq -r "[.items[] | {name: .metadata.name, startTime: .metadata.creationTimestamp | fromdate } | select(.startTime < (now | . - 86400))]" | jq -r ".[].name"
```

Answer (score 0):

> Both of them return the answers but make it extremely hard to parse

If you mean parsing the *output*, then `kubectl --output=json` or `--output=yaml` will likely get you much further toward your goal. I see that you already discovered `jsonpath`, but I find its syntax crazy hard to remember or work with, versus `--output=json` can go into `jq` or `python` or a thousand other fun tools that work with a standard text format

If you absolutely have to stay within `kubectl`, then using [golang text/template](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#hdr-Actions) is almost certainly more powerful, and arguably easier to read, but at the expense of verbosity